# C# custom error response for 424 and 422 error codes

Tags: c#, error-handling, .net-core

I want to be able to return Status code - 424(Failed Dependency) and 422(Unprocessable Entity) from my API. We are using a custom error handlers to handle the error responses as follows:

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ApiResponse(int statusCode, string message = null)
    {
        StatusCode = GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(statusCode);
        Message = message;
    }
    private static string GetDefaultMessageForStatusCode(int statusCode)
    {
        switch (statusCode)
        {
            case 200:
                return "Success.";
            case 400:
                return "Bad request.";
            case 404:
                return "Not Found.";
            case 424:
                return "Dependency Failure";
            case 500:
                return "An unhandled error occurred.";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public class DependencyFailureResponse : ApiResponse
{
    public DependencyFailureResponse(string message) : base(424)
    {
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

When I call the DependencyFailureResponse from my controller I am getting the "Dependency Failure" status code along with my custom message. But, as I am calling it as -

```
return BadRequest(new DependencyFailureResponse("Custom message"));
```

it will be always shown as 400 Bad Request.

I want to be able to call it in such a way that "400 Bad Request" should not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

BadRequest is a controller method to return the HttpStatusCode 400 to the caller.
You could try:

```
var response = new DependencyFailureResponse("Custom message");

return StatusCode(response.StatusCode, response.Message);
```

Comment: this works; but i am trying to avoid putting status code in controller. Instead my exception class should throw the specific error code. Can the error code - 424 be put in DependencyFailure class and from controller i should just be doing - throw DependencyFailure("Cutom message"); and it should still throw 424

Comment: I don't believe so. When you throw an uncaught exception the framework will interpret the response as a server error and return 500 status code. You can either implement an exception handler to handle your specific exceptions or implement your own controller method, similar to BadRequest(...) to return your status codes.

Comment: If i want to implement it as BadRequest(...); how i can do that? how I can make my DependencyFailure() class throw 424 by default when called along with custom message

Comment: You cannnot implement it as BadRequest(...), you would need to write your own method e.g. DepedencyFailure(...) that sets the status code and returns the error. Take a look at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BadRequestObjectResult.cs and also the BadRequest method on ContollerBase (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs) to point you in the right direction